# jQuery not getting the password field value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have searched a lot in stackoverflow and other sites and got many solutions but nothing solved mine.That is why I am posting this.I have a password field in my web page, which was created dynamically on a link click.And I want to get the value typed in that password field into a variable when it loses focus.For that i created a jQuery function like this.

```
$('#parentdiv').on('focusout', '#passwordfield', function() {
      var pass1 = $('#passwordfield').val();
      alert(pass1);
      alert("Hello");
});
```

Here the first alert command will displayed with nothing, but the second alert come with "Hello". Which means, when the password field loses its focus this function executes without any problem, but the problem is, it is not getting the password field value.

Please help me to solve this problem.

**EDIT**

This is my html

```
<input type="password" size=20 id="passwordfield" />
```

Comment: It wouldn't fix your problem, but since the event is delegated to `#passwordfield`, just use `$(this).val()` inside the handler instead of the way you currently are using `.val()`

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/MDFY3/

Comment: Also, it works fine for me with either way of getting `.val()` - http://jsfiddle.net/eD8va/

Comment: Can you show your HTML? what browser are you running on?

Comment: Try to reproduce your issue on http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I dont know why it is not working for me.

Comment: @user2356932 Are you typing in the textbox first? You know that's required in order for the element to have a value and for `.val()` to return anything, right?

Comment: I am using firefox right now. @David Tansey : It is not working here (http://jsfiddle.net/MDFY3/) also , the first alert not showing anything!

Comment: @user2356932 Yes it **is** working. I updated your HTML to be valid (which didn't matter anyways). Type something in the textbox, then click somewhere else on the page. It will `alert` what you typed.

Comment: @lan: dude after typing something in the filed only, the variable pass will get any value. I know that.

Comment: @user2356932 So **what** isn't working?

Comment: @lan: dude its working fine. But insteas of text filed I am using password filed.Will that work ?

Comment: @user2356932 Then why did you say it wasn't working? Several of us have posted fiddles that work. Mine always used `type="password"` and yes it's no different...it works. The others - you could've modified and tested...it's pretty easy to figure out

Comment: @DavidTansey That's not how you write a `<input />` element, and it's not `type="password"`...

Comment: I changed my fiddle...Same happy result. http://jsfiddle.net/MDFY3/4/

Comment: @lan: I tested there and it is working with password field also. Let me post my html.Please have a look on that guys.

Comment: @user2356932 Yes, I already showed it works with my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/eD8va/ at the beginning. The HTML is basically the same as what you've posted. As I already said, you could've tried it yourself. So **what is the problem**?

Comment: Yes lan, let me figure it out. I was also thinking like no need of posting the same html.Thanks guys for great support.will let you all know what would be the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try this:

HTML code:

```
<form id='form'>
<input type='password' class='required' />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#form .required').focusout(function(){
var txt = $(this).val();
$('.required').after(txt);
});
```

or you can check this code at http://jsfiddle.net/92y6b/

Answer (score 2):

My solution based on above idea:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" />
<script>
    $('input[name=password]').keyup(function(){
        var password = $(this).val();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

keyup/focusout may fail when typing very fast, using copy/paste etc.

You may try this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("myPsw").value;
```