# Validate registration form using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have form and I want to validate fields using jQuery. And if all fiels are valid I want to add class to button.
Also passwords field have mask - dots

My html form

```
<input data-field-name="user_login" type="text" id="dhe_form_control_user_login" name="user_login" value="" class="dhe-form-control dhe-form-control-user_login" >

<input data-field-name="user_email" type="email" id="dhe_form_control_user_email" name="user_email" value="" class="dhe-form-control dhe-form-control-user_email" required="" >

<input data-field-name="user_phone" type="tel" id="dhe_form_control_user_phone" name="user_phone" value="" maxlength="10" class="dhe-form-control dhe-form-control-user_phone dhe-form-value" >

<input data-field-name="user_password" type="text" id="dhe_form_control_user_password" name="user_password" value="" class="dhe-form-control dhe-form-control-user_password " required="" >

<input data-field-name="cuser_password" type="text" id="dhe_form_control_cuser_password" name="cuser_password" value="" class="dhe-form-control dhe-form-control-cuser_password " required="" >
```

Button

```
<button type="submit" class="button dhe-form-submit dhe-form-submit--size- validate-button-class">
    <span class="dhe-form-submit-label">Register</span>
</button>
```

Also jQuery code - it seems I can't get changes of password fields

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    ['#dhe_form_control_user_login',  '#dhe_form_control_user_email',  '#dhe_form_control_user_phone', 'dhe_form_control_user_password', 'dhe_form_control_cuser_password'].forEach(
      function(ev){
          $(ev).change(function() {
            alert('change');
            var user_name = $('#dhe_form_control_user_login').val();
            var email = $('#dhe_form_control_user_email').val();
            var user_phone_number = $('#dhe_form_control_user_phone').val();
            var pass = $('#dhe_form_control_user_password').val();
            var pass2 = $('#dhe_form_control_cuser_password').val();

            var phone_nuber_filter = /^((\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \-]*)|(\([0-9]{2,3}\)[ \-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/;
            var is_user_phone_validate = phone_nuber_filter.test(user_phone_number);

            var email_filter = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
            var is_email_validate = email_filter.test( email );
          
            var is_password_validate = false;

        if( ( pass == pass2 ) && ( pass.length ) > 5 && ( pass2.length > 5 ) ){
          is_password_validate = true;
        }

        if (is_email_validate == true &&  user_name.length > 0 && is_user_phone_validate == true && is_password_validate == true ) {
            $(".dhe-form-submit").addClass("validate-button-class");
        }


        });
        }
    )
  }
)
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Which part 'doesn't work'? There is a lot of validation there, You could start by testing each one separately (and checking result in debugger or with a temporary output) to see which validation test is failing . Also your second test for password length is unnecessary/

Comment: I can't get passwords value. Field type="password" and I get empty result for pass  and pass2

Comment: Have you seen this thread [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454087/jquery-not-getting-the-password-field-value) - some answers there

Answer (score 0):

I find solution

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    ['#dhe_form_control_user_login',  '#dhe_form_control_user_email',  '#dhe_form_control_user_phone', '#dhe_form_control_user_password', '#dhe_form_control_cuser_password'].forEach(
      function(ev){
          $(ev).change(function() {
            var user_name = $('#dhe_form_control_user_login').val();
            var email = $('#dhe_form_control_user_email').val();
            var user_phone_number = $('#dhe_form_control_user_phone').val();
            var pass = $('#dhe_form_control_user_password').val();
            var pass2 = $('#dhe_form_control_cuser_password').val();

            var phone_nuber_filter = /^((\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \-]*)|(\([0-9]{2,3}\)[ \-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/;
            var is_user_phone_validate = phone_nuber_filter.test(user_phone_number);

            var email_filter = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
            var is_email_validate = email_filter.test( email );

            var is_password_validate = false;

            if( ( pass == pass2 ) && ( pass.length ) > 5 && ( pass2.length > 5 ) ){
              is_password_validate = true;
            }
            
            if (is_email_validate == true &&  user_name.length > 0 && is_user_phone_validate == true && is_password_validate == true ) {
                $(".dhe-form-submit").addClass("validate-button-class");
            }
            else{
              $(".dhe-form-submit").removeClass("validate-button-class");
            }

        });
        }
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Glad you got it working - but I can't see what you changed, or why it worked